# Is there any JavaFX gui builder?

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, javafx, qml

NetBeans for JavaFX I tried, but its really not stable, lot of things getting often changed and also it does not shift with NetBeans nightly builds. Also I am afraid will JavaFX remain or it will be deprecated by Oracle.

So, I was thinking if there is something else which has more advanced way of doing JavaFX UI designing, as an alternative tools of NetBeans for JavaFX.

Question: Is there any good JavaFX gui builders which generates readable code, with less mess?

Thanks in advance.

ex: http://www.reportmill.com/jfx/

Comment: are you talking about JavaFX2 or JavaFX Script?

Comment: @Gabriel Scerbak: Yes both, because i wrote applications with version old one such as: http://youtu.be/gq3fXjy00KE

Comment: The javaFX Script was dropped by Oracle, but got support from the open source community, it is now called Visage.

Comment: @Gabriel Scerbak: If Visage is the new JavaFX. This would be a really over killing to use Java and JavaFX forever in future projects. It would be nice and easy to go with some responsible language platforms such as QT and Qml. Java/Oracle seems really disappointing technologies they start and drop too fast.

Comment: JavaFX Script was Suns's doing and Oracle argues that their customers are not interested in new languages, therefoer Oracle continues JavaFX2, which is JavaFX APIs in Java, without the new language - JavaFX Script.

Comment: ...recently there has also been news about the author of SWT (Eclipse GUI framework for Java) creator getting hired by Oracle, so it seems Oracle will be trying to do something about that

Comment: @Gabriel Scerbak: SWT GUI vs JavaFX gui has Sky and Ground differences. JavaFX is a fast building technologies which is already getting used by all others such as Qml, Silverlight, Flash (slapped all Gui builders almost).  So what ever Oracle is doing looks like threat for future. JavaFX technologies i hope dont get killed in a idiot IT Politics (such as JMF no further improvement, lead us to shot ourself by doing and living with Java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try JavaFX Scene Builder to create visualy your FXML files. FXML files are the "UI" of your application! JavaFX Scene Builder is only for JavaFX 2.0!

Here is the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/jsbpub-user_guide.htm